# HTML-Agility-Pack's DocumentNode.SelectNodes not able to find specific node

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am using HTML-Agility-Pack to scrape data about domains and IPs from the [Mcafee Threat Intelligence lab](http://www.mcafee.com/us/mcafee-labs/threat-intelligence.aspx), but no matter what XPATH I provide to DocumentNode.SelectNodes it cannot find the node I am looking for (the image for threat level). It can find other nodes and images, but not this specific one as far as I can tell.  The specific img has an id of "ctl00_mainContent_imgRisk" on this page: www.mcafee.com/threat-intelligence/domain/default.aspx?domain=facebook.com (facebook.com as an example). Here is the code I am using:

```
        string XPATH = "foo"
        string url = "http://www.mcafee.com/threat-intelligence/ip/default.aspx?";
        if (y == true)
            url = url + "ip=" + ipaddress;
        if (y == false)
            url = url + "domain=" + domainname;
        HttpWebRequest mcafeeReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        mcafeeReq.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5";
        HtmlDocument mcafeeWeb = new HtmlDocument();
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)mcafeeReq.GetResponse();
        var resultStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        mcafeeWeb.Load(resultStream);
        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = mcafeeWeb.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(XPATH);
        try
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                try
                {
                    HtmlAttribute att = node.Attributes["title"];
                    Console.WriteLine(att.Value);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No Value Found");
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Nodes Found.");
        }
```

I have tried a number of different values for XPATH to find the img including

"//img[@id='ctl00_mainContent_imgRisk']", which returns no nodes

"//img", which returns some img's but not the correct one

the full XPATH to the img "/html/body[@id='ctl00_MasterBody']/div[@class='wrapper']/div[@class='page']/div[@class='container pageContainer']/div[@class='pageMiddle']/div[@class='pageTopGradient']/div[@class='pageBottomGradient']/div[@class='canvas pageContent pageBannerBolster']/div[@class='row pageBanner pageBannerTeal']/div[@class='area primaryContent']/div[@class='bannerContent bannerContentImage']/img[@id='ctl00_mainContent_imgRisk']", which returns no nodes.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath is

```
//img[@id='ctl00_mainContent_imgRisk']
```

all the rest is superfluous cruft.

Don't use XPath that was generated by tools. Craft XPath yourself.

Comment: That is what I started with, but that XPath doesn't return any nodes.

Comment: @enragedcacti Well. There **is** no `<img>` with that ID on the page you linked. No wonder it does not find anything.